# CSV is not parsing properly. Gives 'Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n '

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium and python to do some scrapings.
Python2.7
OS- Mac 10.14 Mojave

> Error is - Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 2).

That means line break problem. I did this:

```
des = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="descriptiontext"]/div/div/div')
            .get_attribute('innerHTML')
            .encode('ascii', 'ignore')
            .decode('ascii')
regex=re.compile('<a.*?a>') #taking out <a> tags
des1 = str(re.findall(regex, des)[0])
des = des.replace(des1,'')

with open("new.csv", "a") as myfile:
  myfilewriter = csv.writer(myfile)

  if len(menuList)==2:
    print (des)
    type,tags=blank,blank
    published='TRUE'
    option1 = menuList.items()[0][0]
    option1Val=  menuList.items()[0][1][0].items()[0][0]
    option2 = menuList.items()[1][0]
    option2Val=menuList.items()[1][1][0].items()[0][0]
    option3, option3Val= blank,blank
    sku = directory
    gram = '0'
    v_inventory='shopify'
    v_inventory_quantity= '100'
    v_inventory_policy= 'continue'
    v_fulfillment_service='manual'
    try:
        v_price = float(menuList.items()[1][1][0].items()[0][1]) + 10.99
    except:
        v_price = 10.99 + price
    v_compare_price = blank
    v_shipping= 'TRUE'
    v_taxable= 'FALSE'
    v_barcode = blank
    v_imgsrc = blank
    img_pos = blank
    img_alt = blank
    giftCard= 'FALSE'
    seo_title,seo_des,gShopping,gSG,gSA,gMPN,gAd,gAdL,gSC,gCP,gSCL,gSCL1,gSCL2,gSCL3,gSCL4,v_image= blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank,blank
    v_weight_unit ='lb'
    v_tax, cpi=blank,blank
    myfilewriter.writerow([handle,title,des,vendor,type,tags,published,option1,option1Val,option2,option2Val,option3,option3Val,sku,gram,v_inventory,v_inventory_quantity,
                           v_inventory_policy,v_fulfillment_service,v_price,v_compare_price,v_shipping,v_taxable,
                           v_barcode,v_imgsrc,img_pos,img_alt,giftCard,seo_title,seo_des,gShopping,gSG,gSA,gMPN,gAd,gAdL,gSC,gCP,gSCL,gSCL1,gSCL2,gSCL3,gSCL4,v_image,
                           v_weight_unit,v_tax,cpi])
```

Not sure what else I can do. The output of 'des' is html of product description. So showing csv version of 'des' renders the html itself.

Please leave your email id, I'd be happy to send the csv file and scrapping code.

Comment: Show us the entire error message.  Also, I don't see where this code uses CSV.

Comment: My guess is that your csv file has a `\r` or `\n` in it that is not in quotes. i.e. you have: `col1\n,col2,col3`. When you should have: `"col1\n",col2,col3`.

Show us more code and show us the full error and which line the error is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Update::
Oh my god! Literally, wasted 2 days on this. Issue was because of the Mac. When used Windows Comma Seperated Values (.csv), it works!....Insane... can anybody enlighten me, what the difference is?